# Help to understand a sentence from my textbook

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I saw this sentence in my textbook.

> Children need to be able to choose how much they eat, **especially with the large portions common these days**. Insisting they clean their plates can lead to overeating later in life.

I don't quite understand the grammar and meaning of *especially with the large portions common these days*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where your difficulty lies. Perhaps these explanations will help.

"Especially with" introduces more information.  It's acting like a conjunction. You could replace it with "especially because of".

"the large portions [which are] common these days" might be confusing because of the omission of "which are".

"these days" is idiomatic - it means: today, or in modern times.

If I were to write it out in a different way, would this help?

> Children need to be able to choose how much they eat, especially because of the
>   large portions which are common today.

Comment: What's the large portions referring to here?

Comment: @dan it means large portion sizes of food